# javascript split undefined array

Tags: javascript

```
var ar= [];
ar[0] = 'abc|def';
ar[1] = ['www|aaa', 'bb|cct', 'oo|kopp'];

for(var i=0; i<ar[1].length; i++) {
    var f = ar[1][i].split['|'];
    alert(f[0]); //error f is undefined 
}
```

Why there is error on split function? I am new to javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split` is a function, not an array:

```
var f = ar[1][i].split('|');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to invoke `split` like this:

```
var f = ar[1][i].split('|');
//                    ^ instead of ['|']
```